# AWS S3: Error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateSession operation: Access Denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am new to Amazon web service management.
I created a directory bucket and user in IAM so that I could connect to my bucket through the Flask app. This is my permissions policy for user:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I want to create a policy for my bucket I get unknow error:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1706996941974",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

I think as a solution I can create new General-purpose buckets but I need Directory buckets since it is faster.

Comment: The policy looks correct and I'll expect it to work. What happens if you try specific action sets in your policy, e.g :           
**"Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject", "s3:DeleteObject"],**
Following least privilege access best practice, this is the way to go, but generally I want to see what the result of this will be.
If it works, it might be a thing of your account or IAM user not being able to set apply such broad permissions.
Let me know how it goes.

Comment: But should I provide policy for the bucket if I already provided public policy in IAM?
I changed the state of permission, However nothing changed.

I want to mention that I can do all granted actions in AWS console. however, given error message returned to be from the flask app.

Comment: <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>019b20cae000018d745ffd60060c8b33778d0e31</RequestId>
<HostId>hostname.example.org</HostId>
</Error>

this is XML file when Im enter to one of the object's RL

Comment: No, your Flask app should be able access the bucket with proper IAM permissions alone. A bucket policy is not mandatory if IAM permissions are correctly set, but bucket policies define access to the bucket itself and they are recommended. That being said, let's take a step back, my initial comment was an attempt to fix the **Policy has invalid action** error you posted. That seemed to be the major issue you mentioned. Now can you share more details about what your flask app is trying to do, how it is assuming your IAM user, and why you were trying to set up the policy that failed.

Comment: The bucket policy in your post is valid. However, you don't strictly need it for the use case you have. Just use IAM credentials. If your Flask app runs on EC2 then attach an IAM role to that EC2 instance and include the minimal S3 permissions needed in the S3 policy attached to the IAM role.

Answer (score 0):

The directory bucket has a different policy than the general purpose bucket. It cannot use `s3` actions. Instead, you should use `s3express:*`. You can see all available directory bucket actions in the [IAM for S3 Express One Zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-express-security-iam.html)